# Why does one function update UseState correctly but the other one doesn't?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState([false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]);
```

The following function will result in the alert showing the updated usestate but the div at the bottom will not have the new state.

```
const onSetFilters = (e) => {
 let ID = e.target.getAttribute("value");
 let filtz = filters;
 if(filtz[ID]){
  filtz[ID] = false
 }else{
  filtz[ID] = true
 }
 setFilters(filtz)
 alert(filters.toString())
}
```

The following function works correctly.

```
const selectAllFilters = (e) => {
  let filtz = []
  if(filters.every(filter => filter === true)){ // see if all are true
    filtz = Array(filters.length).fill(false)
  }else{
   filtz = Array(filters.length).fill(true)
  }
  setFilters(filtz)
}

return(
 <div>
  filters: {filters.toString()}
 </div>
)}
```

Help to fix and understand would be much appretiated.
Also, when I update another part of useState after i used onSetFilters(), then the filters part will be updated aswell.

Comment: state updates are async and sometimes batched. You won't always get the result in the very next statement like an alert or console log - you get it in the next render cycle. So try checking when your component renders vs when you're setting state?

Comment: Oh, and this is suspect: you're setting the variable to the state and directly updating it. React decides when to re-render based on object equality. Try making a new array instead like let `filtz = [...filters];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State updated will never be reflected immediately. You are not making any copy of state in your `onSetFilters()`. You are directly mutating the state here, hence you see a change in value.

```
const onSetFilters = (e) => {
 let ID = e.target.getAttribute("value");
 let filtz = filters; //filtz is not a copy of filters, it points to the same array
 //let filtz = [...filters]; //making a copy here. Uncomment this and you will see that state is not updated.
 
if(filtz[ID]){
  filtz[ID] = false //mutating state
 }else{
  filtz[ID] = true //mutating state
 }
 setFilters(filtz)
 alert(filters.toString())
}
```

Your code above is only **mutating** the state variable and not **updating** the state.

For react to detect a state update, there has to be a change of reference. This comes into play for non primitive values like arrays. The spread operator above will fix your problem of state not updating, because it will be making a copy of the array, and hence a new reference.